# Is chroot the right choice for my use case?

Tags: server, permissions, chroot, multi-user

**Backstory:**

I am working on setting up a MineCraft server and want to allow admins to have ssh access to the MineCraft server console and appropriate mc server files, but not the whole system. The console provided by the minecraft server is only available to the user that launched the process. In addition, the admins will need terminal access to some basic cli tools such as wget, cp, mv, rm, and  a text editor.

**Plan:**

- I have already setup the ssh aspect of things, requiring pre-shared
  keys and whatnot.
- Setup a jailed environment in which all user activity will be contained.
- Setup user accounts.

  - The first user account will be the minecraft user. The minecraft user will start the MC server in a [multiuser screen session](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Multiuser-Session) and allow the other admins to attach to it.

  - Subsequent users should have their own /home directory for normal usage.
- Setup acl for the appropriate files to allow each user to edit the mc server files.

No one will be doing system updates, nor will anyone be installing any programs, so I'll be the only user with sudo.

**The Issues:**

I don't want the ssh users to have access to the whole system. Users will still need to use wget or curl to update the mc server files. I have no experience setting up a chroot environment and have found several tools to aid in this process. [Jailkit](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/) seems to be the most robust, but it's not in the standard repos.

**The Questions:**

1. Is chroot the right tool for this use case, or is there something
   more appropriate for the job?
2. Should there be a chroot environment for each user, or one chroot
   environment for all users?
3. Should chroot be setup by hand, or should I use one of the tools
   available?
4. How will system updates effect a chroot environment?
5. Which chroot tool is the most newb friendly? Which chroot tool is the most robust?
6. Would a VM be a better solution overall?

Comment: This is a typical use scenario for **chroot**.  Not sure what the *preferred* / *recommended* version is for Ubuntu. ***What Ubuntu version?***

Comment: Version? well tbh i'm using debian wheezy.

Comment: This might not be the correct forum for your question ..

Comment: I know this site is ubuntu specific, but the topic is applicable. I've had such positive experiences here that I figured answering these questions here would benefit the community that we all love. :)

Comment: Maybe we could change the focus of this question from my specific use case to something more general. Maybe focus on a simple guide to help users determine if chroot is right for their use case, whatever it might be.

Answer (score 1):

I won't answer point by point as I don't know all the answers, but I will give you these pointers:

- A chroot isn't terribly difficult to break out of. A VM is somewhat harder.
- A VM is much easier to set up and manage as it is a full OS.
- A chroot can have a smaller footprint as it's not necessarily a full OS.
- In either case, the guest environment will not be updated when you run updates on the host. You'll have to enter the chroot or VM and update it manually.
- A VM has a feature which may be good or bad for you: You typically have to provision a fixed amount of memory for it. Minecraft can be very memory hungry, so you might run out with a VM. On the other hand, a VM would be an easy way to put a hard limit on the resources it can use.
- Neither a VM nor a chroot will place any intrinsic limits on what users can do over the network. Only a firewall can do that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did realize that a VM would require its own system maintenance, but didn't realize that a chroot would as well. Would a chroot have a smaller footprint than a VM?

Comment: Yes, because a chroot shares the same filesystem and memory as the main system. The trade off is that it can exhaust both unless you make extra arrangements to prevent it.

Comment: Also, you don't need a full OS with a chroot, which you do with a VM. However, having those extra OS bits around makes it easier to deal with (eg upgrades).

Comment: Interesting. I'm actually wondering if either a chroot or a VM is overkill for my use case...

Comment: Perhaps. It depends what kind of abuse you expect from the server admins :) - in either a VM or a chroot, they could install "bad" things, and generally do anything they could do on the main system. It may be easier to clean up after them though, if they are limited. Also note that you can't usually nest VMs, so it's out of the question if you have a cheap VPS; you'd need a dedicated server or a special type of VPS. That limitation does not apply to chroot though.

Comment: The reason why I'm even considering this "extra" security is because this is my physical machine on my network. I do not want other machines on the network to be jeopardized nor do I want a user to use me as a proxy for nefarious means. Obviously I have firewall rules in place, but things happen. Anything I can do to make it more difficult for an attacker or lower the risk of exposure is a good thing.

Comment: Neither VM nor chroot will place any intrinsic limits on what they can do on the network, so it's pointless if that is your only reason. Use a firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Using a chroot jail is a false sense of security for the most part.  It keeps honest users honest.  If you do not trust the users to log into the machine, you should give them a different machine, a VM.

For network security, attach the Minecraft machine to a different zone on your firewall with very restrictive rules.  If Minecraft is running on the firewall machine, the only safe solution is to use VMs running on that machine.

Comment: I agree with your comments here. I do have the minecraft server on a separate subnet which is quarantined from the rest of the network.